# Call to undefined function curl_version

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I have installed wordpress 4.6 site on ubuntu 14.04 running php 5.6.

The admin page is not visible and i can see below error in logs :-

Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_version() in /var/www/html/files/modules/postie/postie.php on line 274

How do i fix this?

I have verified that curl and php5-curl are installed on our server :-

```
ubuntu@ip-172-39-6-147:/var/www/html$ sudo apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 137 not upgraded.
ubuntu@ip-172-39-6-147:/var/www/html$ sudo apt-get install php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-curl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 137 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo service apache2 restart`?

Comment: Yes multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this eventually.

I had three php installations on my ubuntu box - php5, php5.6 and php7. php5 had curl installed in it but was being ignore by apache. apache was using php5.6. I went to /etc/apache2/mods-enabled and removed all the php links except for php5.

Answer (score 14):

On current versions of Debian and Ubuntu, you can likely solve this by installing the Curl extension for PHP, and restarting the webserver. Assuming the webserver is Apache 2:

> sudo apt-get install php-curl
>
> sudo service apache2 restart

It's possible you'll need to install more:

> sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev;

Comment: apt-get install php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-curl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: It should be `sudo apt-get install php-curl` (which will select the right version for you, not limited to PHP 5)

Comment: Or pick yourself - depending on PHP module you are running on your web server.. Apache for instance: If module is `sudo a2enmod phpX.X` then use same PHP curl: 
`sudo apt install phpX.X-curl` Where X.X is the PHP version/module Apache is using. (They need to match.)

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a bit late, but for anyone struggling, i found a solution to my problem.

My setup:

- ubuntu 20.04
- nginx 1.18
- Laravel 7
- php 7.4

What i did wrong was upgrading from php7.3 -> php7.4, but then forgetting to update the reference in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/site-name.com`, which was still using php7.3-fpm.sock

`fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;` is the correct line

`sudo apt-get install php-curl` did not help, since it installed curl for the version 7.4 and not 7.3, which I was still referencing.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

After this, if you still get issue, you need to install packages by PHP version.

For example.

```
 sudo apt-get install php8.2-common
 sudo apt-get install php8.2-curl
```