# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_version() - Localhost Dev

Tags: php, curl, easyphp

I'm trying to integrate stripe on my PHP project but I have this error on localhost:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_version() in [...]
```

I'm using easyphp with `PHP 7` and in my php.in the line `extension=php_curl.dll` is uncommented.

EDIT:
i'm looking at error log of apache and i've this:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\\eds-binaries\\php\\php713vc14x86x190923224900\\ext\\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
```

Where is the error? What I can do to fix it? thanks

Comment: Make sure your actual PHP version having CURL enabled.

Comment: Which version of PHP used by apache? Seems like you have installed CURL for different PHP version and your apache is using different PHP version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to undefined function curl\_version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001345/call-to-undefined-function-curl-version)

Comment: i'm using the correct versione of php in apache. i'm looking at error log and i've this:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\\eds-binaries\\php\\php713vc14x86x190923224900\\ext\\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Comment: yes I have reviewed your error message can you please look into my answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60414460/2667307

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

> 1. Copy libssh2.dll from PHP directory to Windows/system directory
> 2. In php.ini #zend_extension remove (;) front row ;extension=php_curl.dll
> 3. Restart the Apache server.